# Python Data Prediction

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

I have some data from Intel processors which I am presenting in different types of graphics.

And I also want to make a regression which show's an exponential function where I can "predict" the transistor count after the max year I have in my data (Max: 2014). Eg: 2019, 2021, 2030..

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', delimiter=',')

X = np.array(data['Year'], dtype=int)
y = np.array(data['Count'], dtype=int)

print(X)
print(y)

plt.plot(X, y, 'bo')

plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.ylabel('Transistor Count')

plt.yscale('log')

plt.grid(True)

plt.show()
```

This code shows:

### [Transistor count (Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z90sB.png)

What I have tried is to use Scikit-Learning to create a regression, but I always end up with the wrong settings for the exponential function. And I have also tried some online regression tools, but they ain't that accurate.

I have also looked at [Sklearn Cheat Sheet](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/machine_learning_map/) to find the currect classifier to use. But I am not the well-know with Sklearn yet. I have tried to do it by myself for 2 days with a lot of searching on both Google and StackOverflow, but haven't found out anything that works for my data.

```
[1971 1972 1974 1976 1978 1982 1985 1989 1993 1995 1997 1999 2000 2002 2006
 2008 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2014]
[      2300       3500       4400       6500      29000     134000
     275000    1180235    3100000    5500000    7500000    9500000
   42000000  220000000  291000000  731000000 1170000000 2270000000
 3100000000 1860000000 4310000000 5560000000]
```

This is the data inside the two arrays.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.svm import SVC

data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', delimiter=',')

X = np.array(data['Year'], dtype=int)
y = np.array(data['Count'], dtype=int)

X = np.reshape(X, (X.size, 1))

clf = SVC()

clf.fit(X, y)

for i in range(1971, 2030, 1):
    print(i,':', clf.predict([[i]]))
```

And with this code, the program will predict the data after 2014 as the same value as 2014. ( (2015-2030).value === 2014.value )

I am not sure if there is some settings I can add to the classifier, or if I just don't have enough knowledge about ML to do this.

Comment: I think what you're trying to do may not always yield correct result, since regression is an interpolation model and should not be used for extrapolation. Ref: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/219579/what-is-wrong-with-extrapolation

Comment: Also, please give this a read: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/86258/using-regression-equation-to-estimate-values-outside-of-the-range-of-data

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can perform extrapolation but you should be wary of your results. I wouldn't trust them blindly. For example, if you had 3 years of data, would you put a lot of credence in an extrapolation of 1000 years? However it's certainly possible.

But why use a classifier if you're performing a regression? Try using linear regression instead since there's a near linear fit. The model is log(y) = a + bX.

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression  # linear regression


X = np.array(data['Year'], dtype=int)
y = np.array(data['Count'], dtype=int)

X = np.reshape(X, (X.size, 1))

clf = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False)

clf.fit(X, np.log(y))  # fit the log of y

pred= []
for i in range(1971, 2030, 1):
    pred.append(clf.predict([[i]]))

plt.plot(range(1971, 2030, 1), pred, 'bo')

plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.ylabel('Transistor Count')

plt.grid(True)

plt.show()
```